# TMS Intraweb How to set port manually

Tags: delphi, port, delphi-2010, intraweb, tms

I want to set the port of my website manually, but whenever I use a TMS component, the port will be set randomly.

How can I specify the port of my application while using TMS components?

Comment: Isn't the random port a sign of a demo build?

Comment: how can I understand that it is demo? my delphi 2010 is not demo version, also the intraweb is not demo too

Comment: If you have bought the TMS component, why don't you simply ask the vendor for support. You've paid for support. They'll give you the best support. They know the control better than anyone.

Comment: right now,I set the port manually, but if I drop one conroller of tms, the port setting will upset

Comment: I haven't used intraweb in quite some time, but the random port thing had to do with licensing then.

Comment: Which TMS components?, I use TMS IW Pack & IW and I never faced this problem

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are using a demo version of TMS controls or have not installed either the IW or TMS license correctly